# Ignite cluster different startup times

Tags: java, ignite

I get very different startup/connection times between runs. My cluster has three server nodes. From my client node (actually located on one of the three servers) I want to run some tasks and cache operations for testing. However, when I start the client it may take up to five minutes to actually connect correctly. On another client start it takes just a few seconds with the same client and the same configuration.

In the cases where client node startup takes very long, the difference in log is this:

```
[13:35:31,649][INFO][ignite-update-notifier-timer][GridUpdateNotifier] Your version is up to date.
[13:37:21,794][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Failed to wait for partition map exchange [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=0], node=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008]. Dumping pending objects that might be the cause: 
[13:37:21,794][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Ready affinity version: AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0]
[13:37:21,802][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Last exchange future: GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.122.1:0, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:0], discPort=0, order=16, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1526060111449, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=true], topVer=16, nodeId8=eec8ea18, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1526060121610], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[/192.168.122.1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:47500], discPort=47500, order=7, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1526060116544, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.122.1:0, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:0], discPort=0, order=16, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1526060111449, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=true], topVer=16, nodeId8=eec8ea18, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1526060121610], nodeId=eec8ea18, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=true, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, res=true, hash=2024590198], init=true, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=null, exchActions=ExchangeActions [startCaches=null, stopCaches=null, startGrps=[], stopGrps=[], resetParts=null, stateChangeRequest=null], affChangeMsg=null, initTs=1526060121650, centralizedAff=false, changeGlobalStateE=null, done=false, state=CLIENT, evtLatch=0, remaining=[830bbef7-0344-4955-bdf6-ff90f6d96602, b0105fdc-5298-4f80-94ae-2f1bbd8b42e8, c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875], super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=189344266]]
[13:37:21,803][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] First 10 pending exchange futures [total=0]
[13:37:21,806][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Last 10 exchange futures (total: 1):
[13:37:21,807][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] >>> GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.122.1:0, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:0], discPort=0, order=16, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1526060111449, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=true], done=false]
[13:37:21,807][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Pending transactions:
[13:37:21,807][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Pending explicit locks:
[13:37:21,807][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Pending cache futures:
[13:37:21,807][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Pending atomic cache futures:
[13:37:21,808][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Pending data streamer futures:
[13:37:21,808][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Pending transaction deadlock detection futures:
[13:37:21,840][INFO][sys-#158%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Exchange future waiting for coordinator response [crd=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=0]]
Remote node information:
General node info [id=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875, client=false, discoTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=0], time=13:37:21.812]
Partitions exchange info [readyVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=14, minorTopVer=0]]
Last initialized exchange future: GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=830bbef7-0344-4955-bdf6-ff90f6d96602, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.161], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.0.161:47500], discPort=47500, order=15, intOrder=9, lastExchangeTime=1526060055205, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], topVer=15, nodeId8=c74ff028, msg=Node joined: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=830bbef7-0344-4955-bdf6-ff90f6d96602, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.161], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.0.161:47500], discPort=47500, order=15, intOrder=9, lastExchangeTime=1526060055205, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1526060060363], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[/192.168.122.1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:47500], discPort=47500, order=7, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1526059855998, loc=true, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=15, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=830bbef7-0344-4955-bdf6-ff90f6d96602, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.161], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.0.161:47500], discPort=47500, order=15, intOrder=9, lastExchangeTime=1526060055205, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], topVer=15, nodeId8=c74ff028, msg=Node joined: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=830bbef7-0344-4955-bdf6-ff90f6d96602, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.161], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.0.161:47500], discPort=47500, order=15, intOrder=9, lastExchangeTime=1526060055205, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1526060060363], nodeId=830bbef7, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=true, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, res=true, hash=1568621067], init=true, lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1526059954164, nodeOrder=0], partReleaseFut=PartitionReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=15, minorTopVer=0], futures=[ExplicitLockReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=15, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]], TxReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=15, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]], AtomicUpdateReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=15, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]], DataStreamerReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=15, minorTopVer=0], futures=[]]]], exchActions=null, affChangeMsg=null, initTs=1526060227922, centralizedAff=false, changeGlobalStateE=null, done=false, state=CRD, evtLatch=0, remaining=[830bbef7-0344-4955-bdf6-ff90f6d96602], super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=410898272]]
Communication SPI statistics [rmtNode=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008]
Communication SPI recovery descriptors: 
    [key=ConnectionKey [nodeId=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, idx=0, connCnt=0], msgsSent=0, msgsAckedByRmt=0, msgsRcvd=2, lastAcked=0, reserveCnt=1, descIdHash=310748176]
Communication SPI clients: 
    [node=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, client=GridTcpNioCommunicationClient [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=4, bytesRcvd=961, bytesSent=28, bytesRcvd0=853, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-4, igniteInstanceName=Test Cluster, finished=false, hashCode=474105904, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-4-#125%Test Cluster%]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=2, sentCnt=0, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.122.1:0, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:0], discPort=0, order=16, intOrder=10, lastExchangeTime=1526060116518, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=true], connected=true, connectCnt=0, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=2, sentCnt=0, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.122.1:0, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:0], discPort=0, order=16, intOrder=10, lastExchangeTime=1526060116518, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=true], connected=true, connectCnt=0, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:47100, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:59666, createTime=1526060121775, closeTime=0, bytesSent=28, bytesRcvd=961, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=853, sndSchedTime=1526060121775, lastSndTime=1526060121786, lastRcvTime=1526060241812, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@3f6752aa, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=true]], super=GridAbstractCommunicationClient [lastUsed=1526060121786, closed=false, connIdx=0]]]
NIO sessions statistics:
>> Selector info [idx=4, keysCnt=1, bytesRcvd=961, bytesRcvd0=853, bytesSent=28, bytesSent0=0]
    Connection info [in=true, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:59666, locAddr=/127.0.0.1:47100, msgsSent=0, msgsAckedByRmt=0, descIdHash=310748176, msgsRcvd=2, lastAcked=0, descIdHash=310748176, bytesRcvd=961, bytesRcvd0=853, bytesSent=28, bytesSent0=0, opQueueSize=0]
Exchange future: GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.122.1:0, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:0], discPort=0, order=16, intOrder=10, lastExchangeTime=1526060116518, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=true], topVer=16, nodeId8=c74ff028, msg=Node joined: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.122.1:0, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:0], discPort=0, order=16, intOrder=10, lastExchangeTime=1526060116518, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=true], type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1526060116548], crd=null, exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.122.1:0, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:0], discPort=0, order=16, intOrder=10, lastExchangeTime=1526060116518, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=true], topVer=16, nodeId8=c74ff028, msg=Node joined: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.122.1:0, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:0], discPort=0, order=16, intOrder=10, lastExchangeTime=1526060116518, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=true], type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1526060116548], nodeId=eec8ea18, evt=NODE_JOINED], added=true, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1818763044], init=false, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=null, exchActions=null, affChangeMsg=null, initTs=0, centralizedAff=false, changeGlobalStateE=null, done=false, state=null, evtLatch=0, remaining=[], super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1650837648]]
Local communication statistics:
Communication SPI statistics [rmtNode=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875]
Communication SPI recovery descriptors: 
    [key=ConnectionKey [nodeId=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875, idx=0, connCnt=-1], msgsSent=2, msgsAckedByRmt=0, msgsRcvd=1, lastAcked=0, reserveCnt=1, descIdHash=1306648390]
Communication SPI clients: 
    [node=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875, client=GridTcpNioCommunicationClient [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=8421, bytesSent=919, bytesRcvd0=8421, bytesSent0=853, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0, igniteInstanceName=Test Cluster, finished=false, hashCode=1972519349, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#121%Test Cluster%]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=1, sentCnt=2, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[/192.168.122.1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:47500], discPort=47500, order=7, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1526060116544, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=1, sentCnt=2, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.162, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[/192.168.122.1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, centos_node_2/192.168.0.162:47500], discPort=47500, order=7, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1526060116544, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], connected=false, connectCnt=1, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=1, pairedConnections=false], super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:59666, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:47100, createTime=1526060121782, closeTime=0, bytesSent=919, bytesRcvd=8421, bytesSent0=853, bytesRcvd0=8421, sndSchedTime=1526060121782, lastSndTime=1526060241815, lastRcvTime=1526060241815, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@619e0deb, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=false]], super=GridAbstractCommunicationClient [lastUsed=1526060121792, closed=false, connIdx=0]]]
NIO sessions statistics:
>> Selector info [idx=0, keysCnt=1, bytesRcvd=8421, bytesRcvd0=8421, bytesSent=919, bytesSent0=853]
    Connection info [in=false, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:47100, locAddr=/127.0.0.1:59666, msgsSent=2, msgsAckedByRmt=0, descIdHash=1306648390, unackedMsgs=[GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage, IgniteDiagnosticMessage], msgsRcvd=1, lastAcked=0, descIdHash=1306648390, bytesRcvd=8421, bytesRcvd0=8421, bytesSent=919, bytesSent0=853, opQueueSize=0]
[13:39:21,652][WARNING][main][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Failed to wait for initial partition map exchange. Possible reasons are: 
  ^-- Transactions in deadlock.
  ^-- Long running transactions (ignore if this is the case).
  ^-- Unreleased explicit locks.
[13:39:21,817][WARNING][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][diagnostic] Failed to wait for partition map exchange [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=0], node=eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008]. Dumping pending objects that might be the cause: 
[13:40:43,347][INFO][sys-#159%Test Cluster%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Received full message, will finish exchange [node=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875, resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=0]]
[13:40:43,354][INFO][sys-#159%Test Cluster%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=0], err=null]
[13:40:43,395][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster] Performance suggestions for grid 'Test Cluster' (fix if possible)
[13:40:43,396][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
[13:40:43,396][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster]   ^-- Enable G1 Garbage Collector (add '-XX:+UseG1GC' to JVM options)
[13:40:43,396][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster]   ^-- Specify JVM heap max size (add '-Xmx<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
[13:40:43,396][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster]   ^-- Set max direct memory size if getting 'OOME: Direct buffer memory' (add '-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
[13:40:43,396][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster]   ^-- Disable processing of calls to System.gc() (add '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC' to JVM options)
[13:40:43,396][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster]   ^-- Speed up flushing of dirty pages by OS (alter vm.dirty_expire_centisecs parameter by setting to 500)
[13:40:43,397][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster]   ^-- Reduce pages swapping ratio (set vm.swappiness=10)
[13:40:43,397][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster] Refer to this page for more performance suggestions: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning
[13:40:43,397][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster] 
[13:40:43,397][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
[13:40:43,398][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster] 
[13:40:43,401][INFO][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-1-#122%Test Cluster%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Established outgoing communication connection [locAddr=/192.168.0.162:40742, rmtAddr=/192.168.0.161:47100]
[13:40:43,403][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster] 

>>> +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite ver. 2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270b13cc1f4713382a8eb23b2eb7edaa3a5
>>> +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> OS name: Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 amd64
>>> CPU(s): 56
>>> Heap: 6.9GB
>>> VM name: 78579@centos_node_2
>>> Ignite instance name: Test Cluster
>>> Local node [ID=EEC8EA18-DED1-42CD-AEC7-2AF754644008, order=16, clientMode=true]
>>> Local node addresses: [centos_node_2/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, centos_node_2/127.0.0.1, /192.168.0.162, /192.168.122.1]
>>> Local ports: TCP:10801 TCP:47101 

[13:40:43,406][INFO][main][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=16, servers=3, clients=1, CPUs=168, offheap=16.0GB, heap=19.0GB]
[13:40:43,406][INFO][main][GridDiscoveryManager] Data Regions Configured:
[13:40:43,406][INFO][main][GridDiscoveryManager]   ^-- default [initSize=4.0 GiB, maxSize=4.0 GiB, persistenceEnabled=false]
[13:40:43,413][INFO][main][GridDeploymentLocalStore] Class locally deployed: class TestCluster$1
[13:40:45,026][INFO][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][time] Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=1], crd=false, evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, evtNode=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875, customEvt=CacheAffinityChangeMessage [id=c6771405361-ef621a9a-86e4-426a-958d-c53f0d9c0e25, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=15, minorTopVer=0], exchId=null, partsMsg=null, exchangeNeeded=true], allowMerge=false]
[13:40:45,028][INFO][exchange-worker-#157%Test Cluster%][time] Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=1], crd=false]
[13:40:45,037][INFO][sys-#165%Test Cluster%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Received full message, will finish exchange [node=c74ff028-1676-4f1a-8c95-563763ea5875, resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=1]]
[13:40:45,039][INFO][sys-#165%Test Cluster%][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=1], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=16, minorTopVer=1], err=null]
[13:40:48,545][INFO][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-2-#123%Test Cluster%][TcpCommunicationSpi] Established outgoing communication connection [locAddr=/192.168.0.162:35242, rmtAddr=/192.168.0.4:47100]
[13:40:48,597][INFO][main][GridDeploymentLocalStore] Class locally deployed: class TestCluster$2
[13:40:48,676][INFO][main][GridCacheProcessor] Stopped cache [cacheName=ignite-sys-cache]
[13:40:48,678][INFO][main][GridDeploymentLocalStore] Removed undeployed class: GridDeployment [ts=1526060443326, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@330bedb4, clsLdrId=85655405361-eec8ea18-ded1-42cd-aec7-2af754644008, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionFullMap, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=true, usage=0]
[13:40:48,684][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%Test Cluster] 

>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite ver. 2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270b13cc1f4713382a8eb23b2eb7edaa3a5 stopped OK
>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite instance name: Test Cluster
>>> Grid uptime: 00:00:05.289
```

Cluster Configuration is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- This file was generated by Ignite Web Console (05/11/2018, 23:29) -->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="Test Cluster"/>

        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>192.168.0.4:47500..47510</value>
                                <value>192.168.0.161:47500..47510</value>
                                <value>192.168.0.162:47500..47510</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>

                <property name="ackTimeout" value="50000"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="connectTimeout" value="600000"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="networkTimeout" value="60000"/>
        <property name="networkSendRetryCount" value="10"/>

        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="initialSize" value="4294967296"/>
                        <property name="maxSize" value="4294967296"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="eventStorageSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.memory.MemoryEventStorageSpi">
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="100000"/>
        <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="100000"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Why would the client node connection take so long? And why only sometimes?

Thanks for any help.

EDITED
Warnings during startup:

```
07:19:46.910 [main][1] WARN  org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi-[warning] Failure detection timeout will be ignored (one of SPI parameters has been set explicitly)
07:20:06.953 [main][1] WARN  org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi-[warning] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
07:20:06.977 [main][1] WARN  org.apache.ignite.spi.checkpoint.noop.NoopCheckpointSpi-[warning] Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
07:20:07.012 [main][1] WARN  org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.collision.GridCollisionManager-[warning] Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
07:20:22.373 [main][1] WARN  org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi-[warning] Failure detection timeout will be ignored (one of SPI parameters has been set explicitly)
07:20:47.527 [main][1] WARN  org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi-[warning] Node has not been connected to topology and will repeat join process. Check remote nodes logs for possible error messages. Note that large topology may require significant time to start. Increase 'TcpDiscoverySpi.networkTimeout' configuration property if getting this message on the starting nodes [networkTimeout=5000]
```

Comment: I really recommend running all JVMs here with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`, see if it makes difference.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. I'm still getting very slow startup time. This is a CentOS system with 56 cores and 32GB RAM. I'm adding the warning messages that I get during Ignite startup to the original post.

Comment: Do you have persistence? If so, your startup might be slowed down by WAL recovery.

Comment: No persistence configured. I somehow feel it is related to CentOS and to multi-core and high-RAM system?

Comment: This is strange, can you provide full logs from all nodes?

Answer (score 2):

When a new node joins to the cluster it require to complete current cluster operations to register new cluster topology.
Please pay attention to the warning below.

```
[13:39:21,652][WARNING][main][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Failed to wait for initial partition map exchange. Possible reasons are: 
  ^-- Transactions in deadlock.
  ^-- Long running transactions (ignore if this is the case).
  ^-- Unreleased explicit locks.
```

Most probably you have a long runing transaction or an unreleased lock.

Comment: What can this be? My tests is just starting a fresh cluster with the bin/ignite.sh and the config above? There is no cache or task action configured, the cluster is up only a few seconds. When the nodes finally connect they remain idle because I only want to test connection times. So I think it can't be locks, transactions or GC.

Comment: @DonTequila Which Ignite version are you on?

Comment: I've tested with both 2.3 and 2.4 binary distributions. There is no difference between both.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not actually doing anything in the cluster, the issue is almost certainly related to network issues and network configuration. I would try to reduce the timeouts and see if it helps.

For example, you have `ackTimeout=50000`. It means that after the client has sent a message to a server, it waits 50 seconds for response. If the message was lost, it will only retry 50 seconds later - so a single network error costs you almost 1 minute. Reducing that timeout to a lower value should help on a relatively fast but unstable network.

Comment: It's hard to say more that that, but if you still see this issue try enabling DEBUG logging for packages `org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp` and `org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache` and share all logs from all nodes - these logs should tell more about what's happening during the startup.